# How to work out the X and Y coordinates of a moved pendulum

Tags: vb.net, coordinates

I am trying to make a pendulum simulation in vb.net, to move the string of the pendulum I am using:

```
e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 270, 0, 270, LengthOfString)
```

and then changing the end coordinates to rotate this line around the point (270, 0). This will end up making an isosceles triangle. I will know the two equal lengths (LengthOfString). How would I work out the lower (Not (270, 0) X and Y coordinate of the rotated line.

I have tried to work this out with: Pythagoras (To work out the lower line's length) Trig, after splitting the triangle in half

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the starting angle is let say `φ`, which is known then:

```
sinφ = x / LengthOfString
cosφ = y / LengthOfString
```

The end points:

```
(270 - x, 0 + y), (270 + x, 0 + y)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know what this angle will be, I am not even sure how I will make this pendulum swing with user inputted gravity. Would I have to get this angle from a starting angle which the pendulum is released from then attempt to work from there?

Comment: @JasonWren The `φ` angle(starting angle) is set by you. That is why I said it is known. You need to calculate the the `φ(t)` function, how the angle changes over time, and then use the above formula to find the end points. Your question *How would I work out the lower (Not (270, 0) X and Y coordinate of the rotated line* was about the end points